# ProgrammingError django postgresql on hosting

Tags: django, postgresql

I installed postgresql on hosting and it gives an error although everything works fine on the local server

I poured my site on hosting(jino), where linux is pre-installed, I did not make any configurations myself, only specified the data that they said. The site started working(all except the pages where there was content from the database), then they told me to install an sql dump on the site, then I imported this database to the one created on the site (the mysql command). I don't know how to check if everything was imported correctly

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error says it all - please provide more details like your deployment strategy. MIgrations etc.

Comment: I added all details, which i remembered. If you need more i could add

Comment: Probably missing migrations?

Comment: >I don't know how to check if everything was imported correctly The error you are getting is teh best hint - that not everything was imported correctly. The relation "decision_room" is a Mysql Table or View, that is not present in the current database. Maybe the connection parameters are wrong, Migrations are missing (migrate command in Django)...

Comment: yeah, problem is in migrations(admin panel give the same error), but how to resolve it in ssh console?

Comment: doh, okey problem was in settings i print staticfile_dirs and staic_root so migrate coludn't run. I removed stticfiles_dirs and migrate worked